# Locate input element and send filepath to upload file

Tags: html, angularjs, selenium

I am trying to upload a file using selenium web driver. The UI has an upload button which is inside a div tag. The button has a hidden textbox which is inside a span tag. I am able to locate till the span tag.

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="showUpload" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
<div class="btn ng-binding" ng-class="class" flow-drop="" style="padding-top:30px;vertical-align:middle;width:370px;height:100px;background-color:#eee;border:1px solid #ccc" ng-style="style" flow-drag-leave="style={border:'1px solid #ccc'}" flow-drag-enter="style={border:'1px solid #007670'}" flow-prevent-drop="">Drag and Drop your files here.</div>
<span class="ng-binding" style="padding:0 20px">or</span>
<span class="btn btn-primary ng-binding" flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*,.pdf,.csv,.txt,.doc'}" flow-btn="">
<i class="icon icon-file"/>
Upload File                       
<input type="file" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px;" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*,.pdf,.csv,.txt,.doc"/>
</span>
</div>
```

I am able to locate the input tag by firepath, but the same using java code doesnt work.

`WebElement m_upload = driver.findElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='files']"));` returns null.
Can anyone tell me how to go about this?

Comment: Did you check file singular vs files plural?

Comment: I am not able to locate the input text box. Only then I can use sendKeys() to send files.

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NotFoundException: Could not find element(s) matching 'By.cssSelector: input[type='files']' in the state VISIBLE.

Comment: Yes, I meant: in your html you have type="file" WITHOUT an S and in your selector you have type="files" WITH and S.

Comment: type='file'. I made a mistake. But still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
//Give your file path here
  var orgFile = @"C:\Users\username\Downloads\pdf.pdf";
//get uploadfile input and send pat using SendKeys 
            var uploadFile = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("input[type='file']"));
            uploadFile.SendKeys(orgFile);
```

if any issue then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can not perform any action on hidden element. First, you'll have to perform an action that changes the visibility of that hidden input element.

Also keep in mind that page is using AngularJS and you are testing it with Selenium so there may be synchronization issue as well so better would be test it with Protractor or to handle it in selenium by putting an Implicit or Explicit wait statement before uploading the file.

I think it'll solve the problem.